# Error message for my js code - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie learning JS on the job since few months. I am not sure how to solve this error.

Error : Cannot set property 'GoogleAnalyticsUniversalCart:subscribeProductsUpdateInCart' of undefined

This is the code I am debugging.

```
GoogleAnalyticsUniversalCart.prototype = {
// ------------------- shopping cart ------------------------
listenMinicartReload : function() {
    var context = this;
    if (typeof(Minicart) != 'undefined' && typeof(Minicart.prototype.initAfterEvents)) {
        Minicart.prototype.initAfterEvents['GoogleAnalyticsUniversalCart:subscribeProductsUpdateInCart']
            = function() {
                context.subscribeProductsUpdateInCart();
                context.parseAddToCartCookies();
                context.parseRemoveFromCartCookies();
            };
        // if we are removing last item init don't calling
        Minicart.prototype.removeItemAfterEvents['GoogleAnalyticsUniversalCart:subscribeProductsRemoveFromCart']
            = function() {
            context.parseRemoveFromCartCookies();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that `Minicart.prototype.initAfterEvents` does not exist.. Run a debugger to see the value of it at that point? Even if it did, shouldn't it be a function itself? It is not clear what you are trying to do here.. Setting properties on functions which are functions themselves is a little unusual in my pinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the theme override minicart.js file for your project from your active theme.
That file would be overriding the default/js/minicart.js

goto the section:

`Minicart.prototype = {
    initAfterEvents : {},
    removeItemAfterEvents : {},
    init: function() {`

And you will see that the initAfterEvents and removeItemAfterEvents array declarations are missing. Add them to your js file and this will solve the issue. Generate the necessary js minified files. And you would be good to go.

The typeof(Minicart.prototype.initAfterEvents) check in the controller statement in ga.js is not an array rather is undefined. Declare the arrays as stated above to resolve the issue.

I hope this helps. thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I got the idea what to do.